# How to refer to a tuple with attribute "CS1310" or "MATH 1510"? I tried getChar but not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I cannot find the correct function to refer to Course_number (CS1310, MATH1510) in my program. I have tried to use getChar or getCharacter or GetCharAT, but still not working and got a error all the time.
Please, some one can help me.

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLDataException: Cannot determine
> value type from string 'CS1310'

```java
public class university123 {
    
    public static void main(String args [])
            throws SQLException, IOException, IOException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");// maybe need to delete 'cj'
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException x){
            System.out.println ("Driver could not be loaded");
            
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String dbacct, passwrd, course_name,instructors;
        Character course_number, grade, prerequisite_number; // *error
        int credit_hours, Student_number;
        
        System.out.println("Enter user name(root)"); 
        String user = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Enter password (of root)"); 
        String pass = input.nextLine();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/university",user,pass);
        String q = "select course_name, course_number, credit_hours from COURSE";
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(q);
        while (r.next()){
            course_name = r.getString(1);
            course_number = r.getCharacter(2); // *** error
            credit_hours = r.getInt(3); 
        System.out.println(course_name + course_number + credit_hours);    
        }
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Learn to format the code in your post. Either indent all by four spaces, or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks. I fixed this post.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> `course_number = r.getCharacter(2); // *** error`

No such method as `ResultSet#getCharacter`. See [Javadoc for `ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

You said:

> I have tried to use getChar or getCharacter or GetCharAT

None of those are methods on `ResultSet`. Rather than guess wildly at possible method names, why not read the documentation?

---

By the way, your code has other problems.

The `char` type and its wrapper `Character` class represent a single character. I do not understand how you intend to use a single character to represent a course number such as CS1310 & MATH1510.

Also, you should **avoid `char`/`Character`** as that type has been legacy since Java 2, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, it is physically incapable of representing most characters. For working with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

Best to close resources such as `Connection`, `Statement`, and `ResultSet`. Using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax makes that simple.

Follow Java naming conventions to make your code easier to read. Variables’ names begin with a lowercase letter. And we generally avoid underscores. So `studentNumber` rather than `Student_number`.

You said:

> `String q = "select course_name, course_number, credit_hours from COURSE";`

I suggest making a habit of always terminating properly your SQL statements with a semi-colon: `String q = "select course_name, course_number, credit_hours from COURSE ;" ;`

I can see in lines such as that one above that you are mixing your case. I suggest your use all lowercase or all uppercase rather than using one on column names and another on table names. For maximum portability across databases, use all lowercase. Be aware that the SQL standard requires all databases to store names only in all-uppercase, but every database I know of disobeys that requirement. And, to avoid name collisions with any of the many reserved keywords, use a trailing underscore on all SQL identifiers. The SQL standard explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore in any reserved word.

You never mention in your Question the exact data type of the column. Always note the exact data type when asking about Java-SQL questions.

Comment: Basil, Thanks for all your feedback. I appreciate how you explained why to use lowercase or uppercase instead of mix both of them, how the platforms read the info, and the links you provided me.

Comment: It was my first time coding in NetBeans (JAVA/JDBC) to connect with MySQL (I am not an expert in Java, but I know how to write a program); thus, I was overwhelmed with many information. Before I ask for help, I always do my one research, but sometimes I make mistakes in things like this one.

Comment: Also, I know that the coding is not good, but I need to use the coding from the book as an instruction from my instructor. Yes, from the book. Believe it or not, most of the info that I wrote was from the book. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put the information as "String": course_number = r.getString (2);

```java
public class university123 {
    
    public static void main(String args [])
            throws SQLException, IOException, IOException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");// maybe need to delete 'cj'
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException x){
            System.out.println ("Driver could not be loaded");
            
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String dbacct, passwrd, course_name,instructors, course_number, grade, prerequisite_number; 
        int credit_hours, Student_number;
        
        System.out.println("Enter user name(root)"); 
        String user = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Enter password (of root)"); 
        String pass = input.nextLine();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/university",user,pass);
        String q = "select course_name, course_number, credit_hours from COURSE";
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(q);
        while (r.next()){
            course_name = r.getString(1);
            course_number = r.getString(2); 
            credit_hours = r.getInt(3); 
        System.out.println(course_name + course_number + credit_hours);    
        }
    }
            
}
```